# How GTmetrix works?

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

When I add the home page link in the GTmetrix for analysis does it yields results for the whole website or just the home page?I have some issues only for my home page.I need to have the clear idea is to whether it is giving result for all the pages of my website of just the home page.And if it does analyze the entire website what should be the approach to analyze just my home page?

Answer (score 0):

GTmetrix is analysis only enter URL not whole URL of your main sites. If you want to get idea only about home page than check the particular URL in GTmetrix and get data about that.

Comment: I have passed the particular user for the user creation form but result is capturing for home login screen. ? Please let me know the exact solution to get the results for the user creation form

Answer (score -1):

It analysys only page you have entered to. It check time of script loading, DNS response, generation page time and many other parameters, but only for one page.